# Android Wear 2.0 setting a complication to TYPE_EMPTY

Tags: android-wear-2.0, android-wear-complication

Is there currently a way to call/set a complication's type to TYPE_EMPTY based on its id? I know which complication I want to basically "turn off" or set to TYPE_EMPTY and when I want to, but I am not sure how to access the internal complication system to update the complication without access to an instance of the ComplicationManager.

Essentially how would I programmatically turn a complication off such as manually clicking the complication to "Empty" in the ComplicationHelperActivity?

Answer (score 0):

To turn a complication off for your watch face, you could call `setActiveComplications(int complications...)` which is a method of `WatchFaceService` without the complication that you want to turn off.

For example, if your watch face has 3 complications that correspond to {1, 2, 3} and you want to turn complication 3 off, you should call `setActiveComplications(new int[] {1, 2})`, then the complication 3 will be turned off.